# Lambda Expression Equivalent C++ Code

Tags: c++, lambda

I downgraded gcc compiler for 4.9.2 to 4.4.1, as I know 4.4.1 doesn't support lambda expressions. In the following code, a lambda expression `[](void*d){ dlclose(d); }` is used and facing error due to lambda expression. Can anyone help how to use below code without lambda expression?

```
using libs_t = std::unique_ptr<void,std::function<void(void*)>>;
```

I replaced the above line with the below but it's also not supported by gcc 4.4.1

```
typedef std::unique_ptr<void,std::function<void(void*)>> libs_t ;

m_libs[ lib_name ] = libs_t ( handle, [](void*d){ dlclose(d); } );
```

Comment: Does your compiler support std function?

Comment: @user3906620  Just define a function with such a body as the lambda expression

Comment: yes it supports std

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, can you explain how ?

Comment: Can you provide the declaration of `dlclose`? Why is the lambda even needed?

Answer (score 3):

You can redefine `unique_ptr` specialization to accept raw function pointer instead of `std::function`:

```
typedef std::unique_ptr<void, int ( * )(void *)> libs_t ;
libs_t(handle, &dlclose);
```

Use of `std::function` in this case seems to be redundant because the only item that is supposed to be stored in it is a pointer to `dlclose` function.

Comment: After above changes, error is  static assertion failed: "constructed with null function pointer deleter"

Comment: @user3906620 This means that you are creating `libs_t` instances using default constructor. This is prohibited when deleter is a pointer to function. To fix this create `libs_t` instances supplying nullptr and a pointer to `dlclose` as parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Just try `dlclose`.

No, really. It may run into problems with void return values, but if that happens write

```
void mydlclose(void* p){ dlclose(p); }
```

and use `mydlclose`.